# Toolbar mis-placed Navigation Item React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to put the navigation Item in the same line with the logo, well within the toolbar but It keep positioning as different rows. I have replicated the error in the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-bmi41?file=/src/components/Navigation/NavigationItems/NavigationItem/NavigationItem.js:0-758).

Here's where I declared my code for Navigation "Item":

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const NavigationItemList = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
`;

const NavigationItemA = styled.div`
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;

  :hover,
  :active {
    background-color: #8f5C2;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #40a4c8;
    color: white;
  }
`;

const NavigationItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavigationItemList active={props.active}>
      <NavigationItemA href={props.link}>{props.children}</NavigationItemA>
    </NavigationItemList>
  );
};

export default NavigationItem;
```

And here is where I declared my "Items"

```
const NavigationItemsStyled = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
`;

const NavigationItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavigationItemsStyled>
      <ul>
        <NavigationItem>Burger Builder</NavigationItem>
        <NavigationItem>Checkout</NavigationItem>
      </ul>
    </NavigationItemsStyled>
  );
};
```

Toolbar is where I put my Items in:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import NavigationItems from "../NavigationItems/NavigationItems";

const ToolbarStyled = styled.div`
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #da291c;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 90;
  color: white;
`;
const Toolbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <ToolbarStyled>
      <p>Logo</p>
      <nav>
        <NavigationItems />
      </nav>
    </ToolbarStyled>
  );
};

export default Toolbar;
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `NavigationItemList` needs to be an `li` tag. Not a div or your html is invalid. But to your question: this seems to be a css issue. Use `list-style: none;` for the `ul` and make the `li` inline or use `flex` or `grid` there

Comment: Hi @Dominik, thanks for the information about the ul and li advice. I fixed the issue. The problem was I didn't know styled-components has styled.ul and styled.li so I tried to wrapped normal ul and li with a styled.div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style the ul list.
For example:

```
const NavigationItemsStyledUl = styled.ul`
   display: flex;
`;
```

And then use `NavigationItemsStyledUl` instead `ul`

photo - https://prnt.sc/v7eupk

Comment: Awesome, you fixed my doubts